# Should I have a contract already?

Tags: new-job, contracts

Next week, I'm scheduled to start working for three weeks at a local college I attend, but I haven't yet signed an official contract. I'm not trying to see if I have the job. I've already been given a detailed schedule of how I'll be working with several other people next week, and I've signed several tax and background check forms, and been given a handbook with an unofficial hourly rate.

This is a very short-term job, but is it unusual that I don't have a contract yet? Am I correct in assuming that I should have a contract for even this short of a job? Should I be contacting HR to find out what's going on?

Comment: They may present you with a contract to sign on day 1. I wouldn't call that unusual. But asking doesn't hurt.

Comment: @gnat This question is different in that I already know I have the job.

Answer (score 3):

> I've signed several tax and background check forms, and I've been given a handbook with an unofficial hourly rate.

That may be all you actually get.  If you have any questions you should reach out to HR with them.

Since you are in the US (GA specifically) there may not be a "Contract" you sign.  One position I had was just an offer letter stating compensation and an NDA to be signed and that was all.  In the legal sense that was a contract but not in the normal "This is the Employment Contract with lots of terms including notice period" sense.

I have also had several positions with an actual Employment Contract, one where it was signed the day I started and one where I signed it well in advance.

Overall it varies by company and how Formal they want to be.  Since its short term for a college they may not have all that much paper work but HR can answer any questions you may have.

Answer (score 2):

> I've signed several tax and background check forms, and I've been
>   given a handbook with an unofficial hourly rate.

In some jurisdictions what you were given as all you will be given.

You said that you will  be working for three weeks. It sound likes you are being paid to perform at most 120 hours of work.

Most of my paperwork for jobs has only been a page or two long.